# Como obtener un id de la respuesta Task<IActionResult> en NetCore3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

Buen día, tengo una webapp que realiza un crud a una api, la cual obtiene los datos de un FakeProvider, al agregar un nuevo registro devuelve un id que quiero mostrar en el cliente(webapp).
En el Controller del api tengo:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddAsync(Course course)
    {
        var resul = await coursesProvider.AddAsync(course);
        if (resul.IsSuccess)
        {
            return Ok(resul.Id);//<- con Postman me entrega el id en el body
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

el FakeRepository(coursesProvider):

```
  public Task<(bool IsSuccess, int? Id)> AddAsync(Course course)
    {
        course.Id=repo.Max(c=>c.Id)+1;
        repo.Add(course);
        return Task.FromResult((true,(int?) course.Id));
    }
```

Y en mi cliente web:

```
 public Task<(bool IsSuccess, int? Id)> AddAsync(Course course)
    {
        var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("coursesService");

        string stringData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(course);

        //var body= new StringContent(JsonSerializer.ToString(course),System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));
        var body = new StringContent(stringData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        Response response=new Response();// <- ésta es una clase personalizada
        response.HttpMessage =  client.PostAsync($"api/courses/", body).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {                
            return Task.FromResult((true,(int?)response.idCourse));
        }
        return Task.FromResult((false,(int?)0));
    }
```

donde 'HttpMessage' es una propiedad de tipo HttpResponseMessage. La aplicación funciona, salvo que no encuentro como recuperar ese id en la web que consume la api(el idCourse siempre queda en 0), o como llenar esa propiedad de la respuesta del api

Comment: Aquí faltaría el await: `response.HttpMessage =  client.PostAsync($"api/courses/", body).Result;`

Comment: Podrías mostrarme la clase Response ?

Comment: @Lobos podría ser, pero lo tengo definido como public Task<bool..> Add y no como public async Task<>.Supongo que es posible llamar de forma síncrona un método asíncrono, pero quizá por standarizar voy a usar igualmente asincrono

Comment: Si lo pongo todo el método asíncrono, me da problema en return Task.FromResult((true,(int?)response.idCourse)); .. 'No se puede convertit de Threading.Task en bool IsSuccess

Comment: Especifica el tipo del Task así como en la declaración del método: `return Task.FromResult<(bool , int?)>((false,(int?)0));`

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado la manera, en efecto ese id está contenido en el HttpResponseMessage en su propiedad Content. El truco está en hacer una conversión de tipo de dato porque los métodos para acceder al contenido son ReadAsStringAsync o ReadAsStreamAsync. Se recibe en un simple string `string _id = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` y luego hacemos la conversión con: `Convert.ToInt32(_id)` ya con eso puedo asignarlo a otra clase o hacer otro proceso con el id.